# Javascript Splitting a String

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have a string that I need to split so individual parts can be used in a function.  For example a string coming in could be `502349.19`.

I need to split it so it can be used in some math:

```
50

23

49.19
```

How can I split a string into usable objects? I have seen a few examples of splitting it but they don't state how to use the separated values after it's been split.

Comment: What are your rules for splitting it?  Is it always two characters, two characters, then the rest?

Comment: How do you know where to split it? Why is `502349.19` split this way and not `502` and `349.19` for example?

Comment: This is for lat and long.  The data comes in as a string but I am required to process this through some math functions so the split places are always the same since it's degrees / mintues / seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use [String#split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and use Regex pattern to split as per your needs.  For the specific use case in the question, below expression will work

```
array = "502349.19".split(/(\d{2}\.\d{2}|\d{2})/).filter(Number);
console.log(array[0]);
//=> 50
console.log(array[1]);
//=> 23
console.log(array[2]);
//=> 49.19
```

The regex used `\d{2}\.\d{2}` matches sub-strings of the form NN.NN (where N is a digit), whereas regex `\d{2}` matches sub-strings of the form NN.  We use pipe `|` to indicate that both regex should be used.  Use of parenthesis `(...)` around the regex helps in capturing the match results.  Call to `Array#filter` is needed to filter out blank elements from the result.

Comment: `array` is full of strings, you could add a `map(Number)` after the filter for good measure.

Comment: This is working quite well for what I need.  Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `substring`.
for instance if you want `50` as a number, use:

```
var input = "502349.19"; 
var twoDigits = input.substring(0, 2); 
var twoDigitsNumber = Number(twoDigits);
console.log(twoDigits + 2, twoDigitsNumber + 2)
```

this will result console printing:

```
502
52
```

Comment: parseInt("502349.19".substring(0, 2)) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
"1234567890".match(/.{1,2}/g).map(x => parseFloat(x));
// Results in:
[12, 34, 56, 78, 90]
```

The method will still work with strings whose size is not an exact multiple of the chunk-size:

```
"123456789".match(/.{1,2}/g).map(x => parseFloat(x));
// Results in:
[12, 34, 56, 78, 9]
```

In general, for any string out of which you want to extract at-most *n*-sized substrings, you would do:

```
str.match(/.{1,n}/g); // Replace n with the size of the substring
```

Comment: `"502349.19".match(/.{1,2}/g).map(parseFloat);` gives `[50, 23, 49, 0.1, 9]`.